# add a column with a counter per group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame in python with one column A with numerical values:

```
A    
11
12
13
12
14
```

I want to add a column that contains a counter that counts the number of elements per group up to that index in column A, like this:

```
A    B
11   1
12   1
13   1
12   2
14   1
```

How do I create column B?

Comment: It's a duplicate indeed. Thanks. Should I remove the post?

Comment: @ALollz I think the dup tag dose not fully solve his problem .